# Почему в разных компиляторах код выводит разные значения?

Tags: c++

1. http://rextester.com/ZZGGK27907
2. http://rextester.com/IGXLV67756

В данных ссылках один и тот же код. Но отличается для компиляторов C++ и C++11. В C++ ответ выводится верный. А в C++11 выводится просто `0`. По идее, C++ и C++11 не должны сильно отличаться.

Почему может выводится разный ответ в одинаковых кодах? И где может быть ошибка?

Comment: Пример великоват для одного вопроса. В нем может быть множество отличий, каждое из которых достойно отдельного вопроса. Попробуйте путем разделения кода выявить строку кода, поведение которой отличается между версиями и указать ее в вопросе.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Не сильно вдавался в алгоритмические подробности, но как минимум одно проблемное место нашел:

```
stack<int> path;
for(int index = Q.front().idx; index != -1; )
{
   ...
```

Я попробовал прогнать ваш код на указанном наборе входных данных и обнаружил, что к указанному моменту очередь Q оказывается пуста (не углублялся, должно так быть или нет). Соответственно Q.front().idx обращается к первому элементу пустой очереди. В результате возникает неопределенное поведение. А раз оно неопределенное, то, в зависимости от компилятора, программа ведет себя по разному. Как-то вам нужно этот момент корректно обойти или (если он - не то что вы ожидали), починить код до указанного.